# Passing List<sObject/Wrapper> vs JSON.serialize(List<sObject/Wrapper>) when using action:Function

Tags: apex, visualforce, viewstate

To avoid view state, I know the best practices would be to mark variables `transient` where ever possible or to use `javascript remoting`, which does not transfer view state info with it.

But lets say I have to transfer `List<sObject/Wrapper>` from Apex to VF Page `onComplete` of an `action:Function`.

Will `JSON.serialize(List<sObject/Wrapper>)` help reducing the view state? Or it will be same as passing `List<sObject/Wrapper>` direclty? Because I think even if we pass the `List<sObject/Wrapper>` directly salesforce internally will serialize and deserialize the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use JSON serialization this way. It wastes both CPU time and View State size, as JSON parsing is inefficient, and less compact than the binary serialization that Visualforce performs.